# doxygen - helloworld - class diagram

Tags: doxygen, graphviz

i have a very simple code example. with this code example i would like to use doxygen to generate UML class diagrams.

unfortunatelly, when i run doxygen (HAVE_DOT YES) and graphviz is installed, i just see an empty index.html.

```
/**
\brief hello world
\details this is a very detailed description
*/

/** class C */
class C {
public:
    virtual ~A() =0;
    virtual void do3() =0;
    virtual void do4() =0;
}

/** class B */
class B : public C {
public:
    B() {}
    ~B() {}
    void do3() {}
    void do4() {}
} 

/** class A */
class A : public B {
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
    void do1() {

    }
    void do2() {

    }
}

/** class main entry point */
int main() {
    A a;
    a.do1();
    a.do2();
    a.do3();
    a.do4();

    return 0;
}
```

my first try was with mbed-os 5.8.5 and its doxyfile. there, when i set HAVE_DOT YES, i get call graphs, etc..

when i run the same doxyfile on my program, nothing. do i have to set doxygen tags for each class, member, method,... and only then doxy can pick them up??

Comment: Please specify doxygen and graphviz version. Also show the settings that are different  from the default Doxyfile.

Comment: Make sure the code builds in the first place. Doxygen expects valid code, and class C with a destructor named A is illegal. Do you get any error messages when running doxygen ?

Comment: Ok. In the real scenario, i did the test with my code.
I generated with doxy the default doxyfile and changed: EXTRACT_ALL=YES,HAVE_DOT= YES,UML_LOOK= YES,EXTRACT_ALL=YES,CLASS_DIAGRAMS      = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS = NO,HAVE_DOT=YES,CLASS_GRAPH=YES,COLLABORATION_GRAPH =YES,UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS = 50,TEMPLATE_RELATIONS=YES,DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES=100,MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH=0,DOT_TRANSPARENT=YES,COLLABORATION_GRAPH=YES. It works fine on linux mint, on my windows 7, i have doxy/graphviz on cygwin, here it stopps working and i do not get any log output..